# How to send a DNS query with Additional RR?

Tags: domain-name-system, nslookup

How to send a DNS query with additional RR included?
(from a host to DNS server)

Answer (score 1):

You can use dig

```
dig domain.here
```

Check which nameserver is used:

```
dig domain.here NS
```

Check MX record:

```
dig domain.here MX
```

Check after TXT record (spf, dkim etc)

```
dig domain.here TXT
```